# Training a neural network without having training samples for all possible target values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Let's say I have a dataset containing many time series of a leg-worn accelerometer sensor. Each time series has peaks and the peaks correspond to jumps made by the person that is wearing the sensor. I now want to use the data for training a convolutional neural network in order to make it predict, how many jumps were performed in a certain time series.

The problem I am having is that the CNN should work for any number of peaks/jumps. Obviously, it is impossible to generate a training dataset that provides training samples for any possible number of jumps/peaks, since the dataset would have to be infinitely large then. However, as far as I know, in mutliclass classification, the final layer of a CNN must contain as many nodes as there are possible outcomes.

How should the final layer be designed in order to predict any possible number of peaks between 0 and infinity? Is this even possible?

As an example, find my very basic CNN setup here:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation = 'relu', strides = 1, padding = 'same', input_shape=(3200, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation = 'relu', strides = 1, padding = 'same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(?, activation='softmax'))  # ? represents the infinite number of output units I am asking about in the question
```

Comment: You probably want to do regression, not classification.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy good point, since regression learns a value rather than a class. Do you think a CNN is suited for this or is it better to use an ordinary NN then?